# how can i remove scrollbarr arrow wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid

[image: scrollbar]

I want to remove scrollbar arrow and change the color and round the edges how can i do

Comment: don't put an image, put your code instead please (xaml), so e can make a correct answer telling where to disactivate the scroll. All we can do is give you that : `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disable"`, then you may look yourself where to add it

Comment: I don't want to remove the scroll, I just want to remove the image I marked, but I'm asking because I don't know what that feature is. What I want to remove is the thing at the top of the scrollbar

Comment: SO in fact the image makes sense, it's me that didn't look at it carefully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the RepeatButton Visibility=Collapsed :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
</Style>
```

Here is the [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37366/Styling-a-ScrollViewer-Scrollbar-In-WPF) I found for it, there is full description of all ScrollBar properties.